# Disable synchronization before launchApp

Tags: detox

Is it possible to disable synchronization before/during launchApp (with newInstance: true)? Ideally I'd like the:

```
await device.launchApp({ newInstance: true, url });
```

to resolve immediately.

I've inherited an app that does weird things at launch, so I'd like to bypass synchronization at the beginning and only reenable it afterwards.

I tried something like this:

```
await device.disableSynchronization();
await device.launchApp({ newInstance: true, url });
await waitFor(element(by.id('root'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(10000);
await device.enableSynchronization();
```

but from the docs I read that synchronization is always re-enabled for new instances.

Is there a way to force synchronization to be off so that device.launchApp can actually resolve?

Comment: This is now possible. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible using the launch argument `-detoxEnableSynchronization NO`.

See the documentation here:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#10-detoxenablesynchronizationinitialize-detox-with-synchronization-enabled-or-disabled-at-app-launch

---

**Old answer:**

Detox does not support disabling synchronization on launch, but if a network request is causing issues, you can pass a URL blacklist as a launch argument, which will disable synchronization for that network request.

```
await device.launchApp({
  newInstance: true,
  launchArgs: { detoxURLBlacklistRegex: ' \\("http://192.168.1.253:19001/onchange","https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events"\\)' },
});
```

https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#10-initialize-the-url-blacklist-at-device-launch

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late to post my answer to this question.
As @leo pointed out above. detox synchronization can be disabled at launch time like this

```
await device.launchApp({
    newInstance: true,
    launchArgs: {
        detoxEnableSynchronization: "NO",
        }})
```

I hope this helps someone out there who suffered like me.
In my case, an interval runs forever inside the app. So detox was not able to complete the launchApp command.